# Get a belongs_to relationship from class Ruby on Rails

Tags: activerecord, active-model-serializers, ruby-on-rails-5.2

Here are my models:

```
class OrderItem < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :order
   belongs_to :product
end

class Order < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :order_items
end
```

Here is my controller:

```
def index
    orders = Order.where(nil)
    render json: {'orders': orders}, include: 
    ['order_items'], status: :ok
end
```

I want to also include the product in the order_items. How can I achieve this to get the following JSON:

```
    {
        "id": 2,
        "order_items": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "product": {
                    "name": "abc"
                },
            }
        ]
    },
```

Comment: Is is correct belongs_to :product? A order has many order items and the order item has one product?

Comment: Can you post your schema.rb?

Comment: create_table "order_items", force: :cascade do |t|
     t.integer  "order_id"
     t.integer  "product_id"
     t.index ["order_id"], name: "index_order_items_on_order_id"
     t.index ["product_id"], name: "index_order_items_on_product_id"

Comment: I have been able to solve this though, thanks!

Comment: Please can you change the title to solved...?

Comment: changed it, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to solve this by changing `include: ['order_items']` to `include: {'order_items': {include: 'product'}}`

Answer (score 0):

You can reach this with changing
`include: ['order_items']`
to 
`include: ['order_items', 'order_items.product']`.

More details you can get [here](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/968).

Comment: I tried that, it gave me NoMethodError: undefined method